# Check if ADGroup user is already a member of group Azure. If not, add it to the group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

i would like to check if ADGroup user is already a member of group Azure. If not, add it to the group. Is there another way to improve my script? Thanks for your tips

```
#connect to AzureAD module
Connect-AzureAD

$groupObjID = "0a1068c0-dbb6-4537-9db3-b48f3e31dd76"

#get a list of all members which are already in AzureAD Group:
$members=Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $true -ObjectId $groupObjID | Where-Object {$_.UserType -eq 'member'}

#get adgroupmember that will join the azgroup:
$adgroupmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "test_group" | get-aduser -properties userprincipalname, name

Foreach($user in $adgroupmembers){
Try{
$usersemail = $user.Userprincipalname
$userobjectid = (Get-AzureADUser -objectid $usersemail).objectid

foreach ($newmember in $Userobjectid)
       {
         #Check if ADGroup user is already a member of group Azure.
         #if not, add it to the group
              if ($members.ObjectId -notcontains $newmember.ObjectId)
              {
                Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupObjID -RefObjectId $newmember.ObjectId

Write-Host User is successfully added to azuregroup!
              }
        }
}


}
```

Comment: Your Azure AD is not in sync with on prem Active Directory? This should be happening automatically assuming you have Azure AD Connect set up.

Comment: The company has just been bought and they are reviewing projects.  As I am not an administrator, I create small scripts to help myself...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, one thing to consider, [`Add-AzureADMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) documentation is lacking in details and I'm not sure if `-RefObjectId` parameter can accept a `UserPrincipalName` or if it must be an `Azure ObjectId`.

In case it does work with `UPN`, this:

```
$azUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $azGroup.ObjectId -RefObjectId $azUser.ObjectId
```

Can be changed for:

```
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $azGroup.ObjectId -RefObjectId $_
```

The concept is very similar as the one used on your previous question, filter the `UserPrincipalName` array of `$adMembers` to find those elements that do not exist in the `$azMembers.UserPrincipalName` array.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$azGroupName = 'TestAzGroup'
$adGroupName = 'TestADGroup'

$azGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Searchstring $azGroupName
$azMembers = Get-AzureADGroupmember -ObjectId $azGroup.ObjectId

# This should be an array of UserPrincipalNames
$adMembers = (Get-ADGroupMember $adGroupName).Where({
    $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'
}).UserPrincipalName

# Get the members of $adMembers that do not exist in $azMembers
$adMembers.Where({$_ -notin $azMembers.UserPrincipalName}).ForEach({    
    try
    {
        "Attempting to add user: '$_' to Azure AD Group: '{0}'" -f $azGroup.DisplayName
        if(-not($azUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_))
        {
            Write-Warning "Could not find '$_' on Azure AD, skipping..."
            return
        }
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $azGroup.ObjectId -RefObjectId $azUser.ObjectId
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception
    }
})
```

Comment: I have an error in line 7. $admembers = Get-AzureADGroupmember $adgroupname. I replaced for $azgroupname but still getting an error...

Comment: @ak2595 Oh my, I messed up the variables my bad. Try again (copy paste all code again) and update the `$azGroupName` and `$adGroupName` variables.

Comment: ummm im having another error...
Get-AzureADGroupMember: Cannot find a positional parameter that accepts the argument "class Group {

Comment: @ak2595 What happens if you add `.ObjectId` like this => `$azMembers = Get-AzureADGroupmember -ObjectId $azGroup.ObjectId` ?

Comment: WARNING: System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Unable to bind argument to parameter "ObjectId" because it is null.

Comment: @ak2595 ok then the problem is here `$azGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Searchstring $azGroupName` it has never found your group hence why the variable is `$null`, I can't help you with this, you must know the name of the Azure AD Group you're looking for.

Comment: I also tried this way with the objectID but still doesnt work... 
$azGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId 692b44c0-e95d-4d51-9018-4843543683f05b
well you helped me a lot, i will try to check whats wrong... thanks Santiago!

Comment: @ak2595 are you sure your session is connected to AzureAD? I'm starting to think that's the whole problem hehe. Did you `Connect-AzureAD` before running the script?

Comment: yep i did... I will try to delete the groupe and create a new one... just to see what happen or if i see any change

Comment: This time i closed the powershell, run the scripts again. It works, no error but no members were added to the azgroup. I forced the sync but same result

Comment: @ak2595 I have updated the code to help you troubleshoot the issue, make sure that the variable `$adMembers` is populated and contains an array of `UserPrincipalName` see inline comments.